dynamic size SoA_container with AoS Access
I found this idea in the paper Abstraction for AoS and SoA Layout in C++ by Robert Strzodka (PDF) for applying a AoS (Array of Strucures) access to an SoA (Structure of Arrays) container without haveing overhead:
#define CONT_SIZE 4

struct SoA_Container {
    SoA_Container & operator []( int index ) { return
    reinterpret_cast < SoA_Container & >( comp1 [ index ]); };
    union { double comp1val , comp1 [ CONT_SIZE ]; };
    union { double comp2val , comp2 [ CONT_SIZE ]; };
    union { double comp3val , comp3 [ CONT_SIZE ]; };
};

int main() {
    
    SoA_Container container; 
    container[1].comp2val = 4; // AoS Access

    return 0;
}

However this is only works for a fized size SoA_container. Do you see any chance to adept this for an dynamically sized SoA_container?
Note: In the linked paper there is a section called "Dynamically Sized Containers". I first thought that the author presented a solution for the fized size limitation. However his solution results in AoSoA (Array of Structures of Arrays) not an SoA.

Practically AoSoA has the same benefits of SoA (e.g. vectorization on the CPU, memory coalescing on the GPU) given the right CONT_SIZE so why do you need a different solution?

FYI: Intel had something similar with their SIMD Data Layout Templates but it seems to be gone from newer releases.

You can define a array_zip as an optimized counter part to std::views::zip that only works on same size arrays. Then apply it on SoA members. Using structural binding results in similar interface for both AoS and zipped SoA.

@Red.Wave I think for writing new code zip is certainly the right tool but my understanding is that the goal of these methods is to be able to just replace the containers in some big old AoS code base without needing to touch the rest of the code at all. Although that still assumes that the code has sensible function interfaces and  doesn't just use e.g. std::vector<MyVec>& everywhere which would be harder or at least very hacky to replace with SoA_Container.

@paleonix Old code has been written with old measures. There's not much to do. Most of these layout tricks involve various UB, and are extremely fragile. If new code is supposed to be designed with flexiblity in mind, then the acceptable set of policies should be decided now. Maintainability of your code is defined by the abstraction level of current design. If old code lacks enough abstraction, then drop it and revise totally.

to adapt the approach for a dynamically sized SoA_Contains you can use dynamic memory allocation for the component arrays

This was my first fought aswell, however this is not working properly: https://godbolt.org/z/4xTqnG3d4

The whole trick is that the layout of the container has comp1 and comp2 at a distance of CONT_SIZE in memory. If you replace the arrays with pointers this isn't the case anymore and therefore it doesn't work. I.e. the layout has to be known at compile time.
